# Update XML LINQ from ListBox

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am having some trouble discovering how to use LINQ to update an XML file with values from a listbox.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scripts>
  <script id="3">    
    <name>Test</name>
    <author>Test Author</author>
    <filestoProcess>
      <file>testfile.jpg</file>
      <file>testfile1.jpg</file>
    </filestoProcess>
  </script>
</scripts>
```

and I am updating the "name" and "author" fields using:

```
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("..\\..\\XMLTest.xml");
    XElement uElem = xDoc.Descendants("script").Where(t => (int)t.Attribute("id") == id).FirstOrDefault();           
    uElem.SetElementValue("name", txtScriptTitle.Text);
    uElem.SetElementValue("author", cmboAuthor.Text);
```

How can I compare the ListBox values against the values of the "file" elements in the XML file and then add/remove/update the "file" values in the XML document appropriately?

**Update:**
Instead of comparing the two lists, it is probably easier to remove the "file" elements from the XML and then add back the values that are held in the listbox.

Using this code I am able to remove all "file" elements, but when I try to add the values from the listbox, only the last value is written to the XML file.

```
        // Remove all "file" elements from XML
        uElem.Descendants("file").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());

        // Now add the elements from the listbox
        foreach (string s in lbFilesToProcess.Items)
        {
            uElem.Element("filestoProcess").SetElementValue("file", s);
        }
```

For example my listbox contains: file2.jpg, file2.jpg and file3.jpg, but when I view the XML file after executing the code above I only see file3.jpg.

Any idea why this doesn't write all three items held in the listbox?

Comment: Not **quite** sure what you want to do here...

Comment: FYI, you can reduce your linq requests by doing xDoc.Descendants("script").FirstOrDefault(t => (int)t.Attribute("id") == id); instead of xDoc.Descendants("script").Where(t => (int)t.Attribute("id") == id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SetElementValue was adding a single "file" element and then overwriting the value as it looped through the foreach loop so only the last value in the listbox was stored in the XML file. Adding a new element resolved the issue. The code below is what worked:

```
            // Remove all "file" elements from selected record
            uElem.Descendants("file").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());
            // Now add the elements from the listbox
            foreach (string s in lbFilesToProcess.Items)
            {
                // Add the new "file" element with the values from the listbox
                uElem.Element("filestoProcess").Add(new XElement("file", s));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd step through your code to make sure it is looping through each of the files.  Also double check and make sure "s" is set to the correct file.
2. If it is looping through each file and calling "SetElementValue" successfully it could be related to having to retrieve the "filesToProcess" node for each loop in your "foreach".  Rather than what you have, try this:

   ```
   // Now add the elements from the listbox
   var filesToProcessNode = uElem.Element("filestoProcess");
   foreach (string s in lbFilesToProcess.Items)
   {
       filestoProcessNode.SetElementValue("file", s);
   }
   ```

My thought here is that since you are using Linq it could be a timing issue with how it commits the change to the file and maybe it is just overriding the operation each time you loop, which would be why only the last file makes it.

HTH.